gio mount smb... volume doesn’t implement mount
I'm pulling out what's left of my hair trying to get gio mount to work in fedora 41 (gnome) with the gio mount command.
After much trial and error, I've realized it runs under sudo (but only sometimes - I don't believe anything works under a ssh shell), but as a normal person, it returns "volume doesn't implement mount" - as shown here...
"
-> gio mount smb://myhost.mydomainname.xyz/mysharename
gio: smb://myhost.mydomainname.xyz/mysharename: volume doesn’t implement mount
"
In gui file browser, shares work (I can type them in), but I cannot seem to get the command line to work. Running under sudo is a non-starter, because the human version of me can't get at the share (and it'll be under /var/run/user/0....).
Is there some missing permissions setting that I need to set to enable this? I'm trying to avoid having to resort messing with /etc/fstab for what are ultimately intended to be user-specific shares. Ideally there's a technique that won't require a gui involved - either as a session or even installed).
I know there are a few threads hinting at using dbus-launch somehow, but I've not been able to make anything work with it.  (I am really unclear on what the syntax would be for a command that performs the mount).
It seems like there has to be a way to make this work - any research into fuse mounts point me back to gvfs (or gio), but no clear answers.
